# Shuffle imploded array (HTML checkbox into array)

Tags: php, arrays, explode, shuffle, implode

I have this code:

HTML checkbox names:

```
name="selection[]"
```

Code:

```
$selections = $_POST['selection'];

$selectionsview = implode("<br>", $selections);
echo $selectionsview;
```

This is just to preview the output, then:

```
$selectionsfull = implode(PHP_EOL, $selections);
```

I'm writing to a file using fpopen:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($selectionsfull, TRUE));
fclose($fp);
```

But I can't seem to make the outputs shuffle. I've tried like 10 various methods of shuffling, but can't get it to work. Can you shuffle an imploded array? I also tried exploding first, but it errors out every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm dumb...

```
shuffle($selections);

$selectionsfull = implode(PHP_EOL, $selections);

echo $selectionsfull;

$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($selectionsfull, TRUE));
fclose($fp);
```

Works.

Answer (score 0):

The implode function just returns a string, which can't be shuffled.  It seems like you should be able to shuffle the array before imploding, unless I'm missing something.  You shouldn't need to run explode since you already have an array to start.

```
$selections = $_POST['selection'];
$selections = shuffle($selections);
$selectionsview = implode("<br>", $selections);
```

Comment: Literally just got it right before I saw this post. Thanks for the response, realized I made a very novice mistake here. Thanks again!

Comment: This answer is not correct.

Comment: Can you give an explanation as to why you think it is not correct?